# Jupyter notebook taking forever to iterate over a for loop

Tags: python

I an using the following for loop to iterate over df (droping a row if condition match) :

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
   if(pd.isnull(row["CR Date"])):
     df.drop(index, inplace=True)
```

the df shape 240,000*30
It is working BUT It is taking more than 1.5 hours.
Is there any faster way?
I am using Anaconda JupyterLab

Comment: This does not answer your question. Correct me If I am wrong, after dropping a row, wont index of next row change. for e.g. after deleting row 5, wont row 6 become new row 5?

Comment: @mike Sperry: Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
   if(pd.isnull(row["CR Date"])):
     df.drop(index, inplace=True)
```

by this to drop rows with missing value:

```
df.dropna(subset=['CR Date'], inplace=True)
```

for more information, please look at: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html

Comment: You are welcome, please mark it as the answer if it works